# Joystick en unity

Tags: unity3d, unity

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación en unity, una esfera con dos joystick, el primer joystick mueve a dicha esfera y el segundo hace un zoom, el problema es que no sé como llamar al segundo joysctik para escribir el código necesario, pues lo he hecho y la configuración se va al primer joystick.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el el codigo del joystick uno

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

    private Joystick joystick;
    private JoyButton joybutton;
    public float velocidad;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        joystick = FindObjectOfType<Joystick>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        rb.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * velocidad, 0.0f, joystick.Vertical * velocidad);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

una opción seria:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour {

 private Joystick joystickZoom;
 private Joystick joystickMove;

 private JoyButton joybutton;
 public float velocidad;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {
     joystickZoom = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("zoom").GetComponent<Joystick>();
     joystickMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("move").GetComponent<Joystick>();
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update ()
 {
     /* Lógica para cualquier caso. */

 }
}
```

- Lo podrías hacer también con listas, arrays para no hacer dos variables "joystick". Colocándole a la clase joystick el nombre si deseas.

  ```
  List<Joystick> Joysticks;
  ```
- Igualmente tienes la opción de tomar el gameobject "canvas" y los buscas en sus hijos por nombre o index.

  ```
  GameObject.Find("canvas").transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Joystick>;
  GameObject.Find("canvas").transform.Find("Fixed Joystick zoom").GetComponent<Joystick>;
  ```

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, esta es la mas rápida, igualmente tienes la opción de buscarlo por nombre.

```
joystickZoom = GameObject.Find("Fixed Joystick zoom").GetComponent<Joystick>();
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchìsimas gracias por la ayuda, recién estoy aprendiendo, me ayudaste bastante :)

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema es que solo estas "llamando al primer joystick"

```
void Start ()
{
    joystick = FindObjectOfType<Joystick>();
}
```

Deberias tratar de obtener ambos de la siguiente manera y usarlos a tu conveniencia:

```
void Start ()
{
    joysticks = FindObjectsOfType<Joystick>();
    joystickMovement = joysticks[0];
    joystickZoom = joysticks[1];
}
```

Asegurate de no tener mas de 2 obtejos de tipo "Joystick" en la escena. Saludos